# Чем можно заменить content_type text что бы он считал цифры тоже текстом?

Tags: python, telebot

Вот допустим у меня есть проверка если это текст:

```
def process_TO2_step(message):
    try:
        if message.content_types == 'text':
            service_data.update({'photoTO1': message.text})

            msgs = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msgs, process_TOphoto4_step)
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, 'Это не текст')
            process_TO1_step(message)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')
```

Но если я ввожу цифры у меня пишет `oooops`.

Подскажите чем можно заменить `content_type text` что бы он мог за текст считать еще и цифры?

Comment: принтаните сперва свою ошибку которая в `e` находится и посмотрите что у вас ломается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def start(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():  # если сообщение цифра(ы)
       print('цифры')
    else:
       print('буквы')
```